# Python find substring between two markers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Please note i have read other answers on here but they havent worked for me (or I have applied them incorrectly, sorry if I have).

I have a list which I have then converted to Dataframe. I have then converted to string using:

```
df['URL'] = pd.Series(df['URL'], dtype="string")
```

However, when i go to use .find, .partition I get the error:

```
df['URL'].find('entry/')

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'
```

string is as follows and i need to get the unique number between 'entry/' and '/event'. How can i do this?

```
https://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/349289/event/14
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using a DataFrame?

Comment: Just learning python at the moment and its part of a bigger piece of code so I am trying out new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`Series.str` to access values of the series as strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling) so that you can start applying the string method(like `.find`, `partition`).

But a better approach in this case would be use `extract` which allows to [extract capture groups in the regex `entry/(\d+)/event` as columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['URL'].str.extract("entry/(\d+)/event", expand=False)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Please could you explain the (\d+) part and what it does?

Comment: @mgd6 It's a regex capturing group. It's a way to tell that I need to capture one or more occurrences(`+`) of digits(`\d`). Hence the pattern `\d+`

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense, thank you! I will do some research on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you just had a plain string (the URL) then you could isolate the value using a regular expression like this:

```
import re

url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/entry/349289/event/14'

if (g := re.search(r'(?<=entry/)(\d+?)(?=/event)', url)):
    print(g.group(1))
else:
    print('Not found')
```

**Output:**

```
349289
```